# javascript - how to make a list of attribute from a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a object list

```
[A, A, A]
```

contains:

```
A{a:1}
```

and how can I make a list for all the a in A's list

note: i dont hope for a copy of attributes' list, i wanna the list of attributes' themselves.

Comment: so you want an array containing the values of the `a` property on each `A` object, is that correct?

Comment: if you need property names then `var attrList = objList.map(v => Object.keys(v));`. If you need values of a then `var aList = objList.map(v=>v.a);` If you need only values without names then `var valueList = objList.map(v => [...v]);` If you need both attributes and values as object then `var attrMap = objList.map(v => Object.keys(v).map (key => {[key]: v[key]}));`

Comment: You may need to work a little on your question it's unclear..... Please spend enough time making good questions if you want quality answers

Comment: i think i need those values, and when i modify in new list, the old object list should also change

Answer (score 3):

Check the map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

You can do somthing like:

```
 aArray.map(function(A) {return A[a];})
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used to extract a property for each item in a list:

```js
let arr = [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 } ];
let mapped = arr.map(v => v.a);

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for more than a single property, and you do not know or want to code each property's name, you can make it generic to pair up a property name with an array of values like so:

```js
function A(val) {
  this.a = val;
  this.b = val + 1;
  this.c = val + 2;
}
var arr = [new A(1), new A(2), new A(3)];

var values = arr.reduce(function(obj, curr) {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach(function(key) {
    if (obj[key]) {
      obj[key].push(curr[key]);
    } else {
      obj[key] = [curr[key]];
    }
  });
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(values);
```